# SimpleStorageResource doesn't support virtual host style urls for S3

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

Does [SimpleStorageResource](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-core/latest/org/springframework/cloud/aws/core/io/s3/SimpleStorageResource.html) support [virtual host style urls](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/)?

Comment: Looks like there is an open issue - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/686